# `onstatechange` funciton in JSlider is not working properly

Tags: jquery, jslider

I'm using [egorkhmelev's](https://github.com/egorkhmelev/jslider) slider, in its arguments we can pass function named `onstatechange`(works when handle is dragged). I want the min and max value on this function. following is my code([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/ZmzQ8/)):
JQ:

```
jQuery("#Slider2").slider({
    from: <?= $mn?>, 
    to: <?= $mx?>, 
    step: 1,
    round: 1, 
    skin: 'plastic',
    limits:true,
    heterogeneity: ['90/50000'],
    onstatechange:function(){console.log($('#Slider2').slider("value"))},
});
```

HTML:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; padding: 0 5px;"><input id="Slider2" type="slider" name="price" value="<?= $mn?>;<?= $mx ?>" /></span>
```

it is logging the maximum and minimum values, but problem is it is creating another slider all by itself. so i've no idea how to stop that. this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/ZmzQ8/), if you check this fiddle, there are two ranges coming one is from 0 to 10 and another is 0 to 100. so this 0 to 10 came by itself. how to fix this. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `onstatechange` function like so:

```
jQuery("#Slider2").slider({
  from: 0, 
  to: 100, 
  step: 1,
  round: 1, 
  skin: 'plastic',
  limits:true,
  heterogeneity: ['90/50'],
  onstatechange:function(value){console.log(value)},
 });
```

You were creating a new slider with default values in your code in the `onstatechange` function.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/ZmzQ8/1/).